# Plot points for every 15 minutes

Tags: r, statistics

I have a text file having the numbers(of float type) which represents time in seconds. I wish to represent the number of occurances every 15 minutes. The sample of my file is:

```
0.128766
2.888977
25.087900
102.787657
400.654768
879.090874
903.786754
1367.098789
1456.678567
1786.564569
1909.567567
```

for first 900 seconds(15 minutes), there are 6 occurances. I want to plot that point on y axis first. Then from 900-1800(next 15 minutes), there are 4 occurances. So, i want to plot 4 on my y-axis next. This should go on...

I know the basic plot() function, but i don't know how to plot every 15 minutes. If there is a link present, please guide me to that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findInterval()`:

```
counts <- table(findInterval(x, seq(0, max(x), 900)))
counts

1 2 3 
6 4 1
```

It's easy to plot:

```
plot(counts)
```

[image]

Comment: yeah plot(counts) is giving me the line plot. How to plot a curve for the counts?

Comment: @JustinCarrey That's a different question. Read the help for `?lines`, `?points`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Andrie's answer. You can add `plot(counts, type = 'p')` to plot points or `plot(counts, type = 'l')` to plot a connected line. If you want to plot a curve for the counts you would need to model it using `?lm` or `?nls`.